# Return the ls -l output in docker container

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

So I have a docker container running which has a couple of folder/files inside.

When I go inside the container I can see that they are:

> hostmachine$> docker exec -it testContainer bash
>
> testContainer@testContainer:~$ ls -l

```
total 40200
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     41156267 Apr 11 20:10 herp-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT-ap3.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Apr 11 20:10 var
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Apr 11 20:10 herp-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     39 Apr 11 20:10 current -> /home/testContainer/herp-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT
```

---

My question is:

What script, how can I use it on my hostmachine that will:

1) Echo back (return) the following info from the container:

"**current -> /home/testContainer/herp-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT**"

2) And then taking it further, just echo back the last bit:

**herp-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT**

So essentially it could be like:

> hostmachine$> ./getSnapshotName.sh
>
> herp-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just build it up in steps. First, no need to use `-it` and `bash` to run an interactive shell, just run the command directly:

```
$ docker exec testContainer ls -l current
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     39 Apr 11 20:10 current -> /home/testContainer/herp-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT
```

Next, use `readlink` to save you from parsing the `ls` output:

```
$ docker exec testContainer readlink current
/home/testContainer/herp-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT
```

Finally, run that through `basename` to strip out the directory parts:

```
$ basename $(docker exec testContainer readlink current)
herp-4.2.2-SNAPSHOT
```